# Separate total by year with a query

Tags: php, sql

I have a query that displays the total number of products ordered by a customer. I would like to display the number of products ordered in 2012 and 2013.

That's what I get:

```
PRODUCT CODE PRODUCT NAME TOTAL
ABRX58        RED WHINE   1000
ABRX45        WHITE WINE  4000
ABRX32        CHAMPAGNE   3500
```

I would like to have:

```
PRODUCT CODE PRODUCT NAME TOTAL 2012 TOTAL 2013
ABRX58        RED WHINE   500           500
ABRX45        WHITE WINE  2000          2000
ABRX32        CHAMPAGNE   1000          2500
```

My query :

```
 <?php
 foreach ($query=$db->query("SELECT
     t1.PRD_ID, t1.PRD_CODE, t1.PRD_CONT_ID, t1.PRD_COND_ID,  t1.PRD_LIBELLE
     t2.LGCM_ID, t2.LGCM_PRD_ID, t2.LGCM_CMD_ID, SUM(t2.LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE) AS SUM_LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE,
     t3.CMD_ID, t3.CMD_DATE, t3.CMD_CLT_ID
     FROM products t1
     INNER JOIN command_line t2
     ON t1.PRD_ID = t2.LGCM_PRD_ID
     INNER JOIN commands t3
     ON t2.LGCM_CMD_ID = t3.CMD_ID
     WHERE t3.CMD_CLT_ID = $cltId AND STR_TO_DATE(t3.CMD_DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '".$datedeb."' AND '".$datefin."' GROUP BY t1.PRD_CODE") AS $donnees):
     ?>
```

I tried to use a condition such as `SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(t3.CMD_DATE, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2012 THEN t2.LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE_2012` and it doesn't work .

Comment: make a foreach loop taking year as argument and add the year condiion condition to your query....

Comment: Something like that : YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(t3.CMD_DATE, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS YEAR_ARGUMENT ? And after that what should i do if i want to have the possibility to display 2012 or 2013 . ?

Comment: Your query returns a dozen columns and your desired results have only four.  Can you fix your question so the code matches the results you are talking about?

Comment: I understood but i care just about PRD_CODE, PRD_LIBELLE (means product name) and LGCM_QTE_COMMANDE (means QTY) . It's just for illustrate . CMD_DATE is also very important

Comment: help please :/ I'm stuck...